# Do Innodb transactions block reads or order by?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of many rows with an indexed column that I order on. I have transactions which update a single row of this particular table and changes the value of that indexed column (as well as some other values in the row)

My questions are:

1. If I try to read a row whilst it's being updated by the transaction can I do so? Or is the read blocked until the transaction completes?
2. The transactions I do specifically update the indexed column, which I am sorting over with an "order by" query. Can the SELECT * ... ORDER BY query run ok without being blocked by these transactions? Or does it have to wait until the transaction modifying the indexed column I am sorting over is finished?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about the behaviour of transactions, and the best way to fully 
 understand the behaviour of your system is to read about [Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) and take a look at which transaction isolation level your database is running.

In general though, you'll find that when a row is being updated, it is locked with an Exclusive lock, and therefore unavailable until the transaction completes.

To answer your questions more directly.

1. Check if you're running in Read committed or read uncommitted, this
   can have a difference one whether or not you can read the row while
   it's being updated.

   2. The transaction isolation level will play into this the same.